# Regex replace with correct spacing

Tags: python, regex, replace, str-replace, cjk

I need help on some regex problem with chinese characters in python.

"拉柏多公园" is the correct form of the word, but in a text i found "拉柏 多公 园", what regex should i use to replace the characters.

```
import re

name = "拉柏多公园"
line = "whatever whatever it is then there comes a 拉柏 多公 园 sort of thing"
line2 = "whatever whatever it is then there comes another拉柏 多公 园 sort of thing"
line3 = "whatever whatever it is then there comes yet another 拉柏 多公 园sort of thing"
line4 = "whatever whatever it is then there comes a拉柏 多公 园sort of thing"

firstchar = "拉"
lastchar = "园"
```

i need to replace the strings in the lines so that the output line will look like this

```
line = "whatever whatever it is then there comes a 拉柏多公园 sort of thing"
line2 = "whatever whatever it is then there comes another 拉柏多公园 sort of thing"
line3 = "whatever whatever it is then there comes yet another 拉柏多公园 sort of thing"
line4 = "whatever whatever it is then there comes a 拉柏多公园 sort of thing"
```

i tried these to but the regex is badly structured:

```
reline = line.replace (r"firstchar*lastchar", name) #
reline2 = reline.replace ("  ", " ")
print reline2
```

can someone help to correct my regex?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe just search for something like `\s*(character)\s*(character2)\s*...` and so on, and then replace it with `($1)($2)($3)...` to include the spaces around the edges only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume you're using python 3, since you're using unicode characters in regular strings. For python 2, add `u` before each string literal.)

### Python 3

```
import re

name = "拉柏多公园"
# the string of Chinese characters, with any number of spaces interspersed.
# The regex will match any surrounding spaces.
regex = r"\s*拉\s*柏\s*多\s*公\s*园\s*"
```

So you can replace each string with

```
reline = re.sub(regex, ' ' + name + ' ', line)
```

### Python 2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

name = u"拉柏多公园"
# the string of Chinese characters, with any number of spaces interspersed.
# The regex will match any surrounding spaces.
regex = ur"\s*拉\s*柏\s*多\s*公\s*园\s*"
```

So you can replace each string with

```
reline = re.sub(regex, u' ' + name + u' ', line)
```

### Discussion

The result will be surrounded by spaces. More generally, if you want it to work at the start or end of the line, or before commas or periods, you'll have to replace `' ' + name + ' '` with something more sophisticated.

Edit: fixed. Of course, you have to use the `re` library function.

Comment: i forced a reload(sys) to make unicode work as strings, i'm still working on python 2.X. let me try out the code and see what problem surfaces.

Comment: @2er0: if you're using python 2, make sure you use Unicode strings (u"text").

Comment: is there anyway of not hardcoding the \s in between the characters? actually name = [] of different chinese words with unknown number of characters?